# Serana won't come out of the tomb/barrow

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, skyrim-dawnguard

Ok so I started the Dawnguard DLC quest line and got to the point where you first find Serana and get her out of her box after you solve the puzzle.

But I can't get her to move out from there even using console scripts, unrelenting force, magic and anything else that came to mind. Is there a way to get her to move from there so I can continue the quest line?

I can't load a save before I found her to go through all the dialog again because I don't have one the auto save overwrote it already.

Comment: What system are you playing on? XBox, Ps3, PC? If it is a console there is nothing you can do except load an older save, since there is no ingame console available.

Comment: Too much unix.stackexchange.com - I read the title as "tomb" + backspace + "arrow".

Comment: i am using a PC

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these commands in the console?

```
prid 02002b74 (enter)
moveto player (enter)
```